# slack revoke authorization for 3rd party app

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am creating a training environment for a 3rd party app linked to slack.  In the training, I want users to link a 3rd party app (not my app) to a slack account.  I do control the user accounts in slack, and I am the workspace owner in slack.

When the training is done, I want to clean up the accounts by revoking the 3rd party authorization for all accounts in slack.  I'd like to script this, and use the API to revoke the authorization.  However, all of the endpoints that I look at seem to require that it be done by the 3rd party app itself (or at least to have secrets that I don't have).

Is there a way for me to do this through the Slack API?

Comment: Interesting. Initially I thought it should be possible. But what you are trying to do is use your app to delete other apps, which seems a bit more complex.

Comment: Thanks for replying, eemz.  It doesn't look like there is a way for me to do it -- but you gave me an idea.  I do work for the company that integrates with Slack, so perhaps I can talk to my engineers to see if there is a way to do it through our app directly.